# How considering $f(x_0) > c$ and $f(x_0) \le c$ together leads to $f(x_0) = c$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

While reading the proof of The Intermediate Value Theorem, I faced with a question. I am writing necessary parts of the proof just to ask the part that I didn't understand:

Suppose that the function $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous. Let $a_1 = a$ and $b_1 = b$. Define two sequences in $[a,b]$. i.e., ${\{a_n}\}$ and ${\{b_n}\}$ and suppose there is a point $x_0$ in $[a, b]$ to which both ${\{a_n}\}$ and ${\{b_n}\}$ converge. And suppose for all indices $n$, $f(a_{n+1}) \le c$ and $f(b_{n+1}) > c$ and $f(a) < c < f(b)$. Since $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous at $x_0$, the image sequences ${\{f(a_n)}\}$ and ${\{f(b_n)}\}$ converge to $f(x_0)$. It follows that $f(x_0) \le c$ since $f(a_n) \le c$ for each index $n$, and that $f(x_0) > c$ since $f(b_n) > c$ for each index $n$. Consequently, $f(x_0) = c$.

How considering $f(x_0) > c$ and $f(x_0) \le c$ together leads to $f(x_0) = c$? It must be $f(x_0) \ge c$ and $f(x_0) \le c$ together.

Comment: If $f(b_n) > c$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, you can only conclude that $f(x_0) \geq c$. The strict inequality does not pass to the limit. For instance, $1/n > 0$ for all $n$, but $\lim 1/n = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small mistake in your argument: when you go to limits, strict inequalities are not preserved.

If $f(b_{n+1}) >c$ you can only conclude that $\lim f(b_{n+1}) \geq c$.

This can easely be proven with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit.

To understand why we cannot have strict inequalities, consider that $\frac{1}{n} >0$ but 
$$\lim_n \frac{1}{n} =0$$

**Added** To prove that if $x_n > a$ and $\lim_n x_n =b$ then $b \geq a$, you assume by contradiction that $b <a$. Chose $\epsilon$ such that $b < a-\epsilon$ (for example $\epsilon = \frac{a-b}{2}$) and write the definition of $\lim_n x_n=b$ for this $\epsilon$. You'll get a contradiction.

Comment: Honestly in the book it was "$f(x_0) \ge c$ since $f(b_n) > c$ for each index $n$". I changed it because I wasn't reasonable for me (and I thought it's a print mistake!) before you (also @PrahladVaidyanathan) wrote me example of $\frac{1}{n} >0$. Would you please let me know how can I prove the general case by $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit? It's really hard for me! Thank you.

Comment: @AlphaE Added a sketch of the proof.